# Temporarily disable SDL event queue?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm making a slot machine game, and I've been on the problem of preventing multiple spins from being queued up. The spinReelsRandom() function is what starts a series of loops that generate random numbers in here.

The game operates perfectly right now except for the fact that a player who repeatedly hits the Space button during a spin (common practice for slot players) is queuing up spins that play out immediately after the user is done. I want to ignore input starting right after the first time the user presses the spacebar to start the spin until the spinReelsRandom() function is complete.

What I've already tried:

- I'm able to get the desired result by using SDL_SetEventFilter (commented out below) in the main loop. My eventFilter is simply returning 1. However, for some reason, this prevents SDL_Quit from working. My guess as tp why this works is because the filter is only returning 1 while there are no events waiting to be polled since it's outside the event polling loop, preventing users from queuing spins until the spinReelsRandom function is complete. If there's an explanation, and a way to re-enable SDL_Quit, this could be it!
- Moving the filter into the procedure right after pressing the spacebar doesn't seem to work, and I've tried following up with a SDL_SetEventFilter(NULL, NULL) to reset the event filter after the spin is complete but it doesn't seem to work.
- I've also tried using an "isSpinning" flag that flips true while the reel is spinning and using a check on initiating a spin, but as soon as the flag flips back to false once the spin is complete, the additional polled spins begin.

Is there something I can be doing with SDL_PeepEvents?

Here's the main loop after initialization, with my event being "e":

```
while (!quit)

        {
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)

            {           

// When an event is polled, this sets a filter to stop polling for more events until that action is completed.
// Note: This is what's stopping the repeated spins, however it has disabled the quit functionality.
                // SDL_SetEventFilter(eventFilter, &e);

                switch (e.type)
                {

                case SDL_QUIT:

                    quit = true;

                    break;

                case SDL_KEYDOWN:

                    switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
                    {

                    case SDLK_SPACE:

                        //Function that continuously spins the reels until they reach a random destination
                        spinReelsRandom();

                        SDL_Delay(25);

                        break;

                    case SDLK_0:

                        cout << "This works";

                        break;

                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:

                        quit = true;

                        break;
                    }

                }

                //Final Spin Cleanup
                spinCleanup();

    }
}
```

Comment: Event loop should not perform any simulations, especially not `SDL_Delay` and alike. Simulated action (like spinning) often takes multiple frames to complete, and for that time other actions should not be stopped - which is very difficult to do if your action is implemented in long blocking function. Set the flag that action is started, and on each frame (or each simulation frame) perform incremental step, after that it becomes trivial to filter out request to start action that is already running. As it written now, I suppose you can't even quit while spinning?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you've helped quite a bit! To rephrase your advice in the context of my issue, instead of updating the reels in a separate loop within the event loop, the program is now one big loop that polls for an event, checks the spin flag, increments each of the reels closer to the destination if the flag is open, then renders the reels at their positions.  Players can now quit even while the reels are spinning, too! I spoke with some experienced programmers and they mentioned that loops within loops are always bad news! That was really the root issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second condition:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0 && quit == false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this did not resolve the issue, I was polling for a quit event within the loop already. Keltar's advice did solve the issue, though!

Comment: thats great. From now on though, to keep waste out of Stack, i will not answer a question in which I am sure about being "unsure". Wrong guesses just confuse those who read them, no use

Answer (score 0):

Keltar's solution only works when your 'spinReels' (or any other time-consuming function) can be separated into chunks that are fast enough to leave time for the main event loop to  handle the rate at which new events are coming in.

If that is not the case, you have 2 alternatives:

1) Put another event loop into the blocking function. There you can react very specifically to incoming events in a different way than in the main loop. (Either react in some way, or, which can be very useful, discard unwanted events, if you want the blocking function to complete. In your example: Abort function on Escape, but maybe ignore Space? For the latter, you could simply discard all queued SDLK_SPACE events.)

2) Put the blocking function into a separate thread, and use the main event loop to set signals to your threaded function.